# Bootstrap 3 - Full width coloured blocks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I really want full width colour blocks to represent different sections of my webpage.

I am using bootstrap 3 to build my website. The website is in a container from the standard bootstrap but I would liked some of the sections to be colouful blocks that span the full browser windows.

Does anyone know how this is done and can post an example please?

Comment: look up 'CSS' and look for 'background-color'

Comment: It only seems to leave a small block of colour and does not stretch t the full width.

Comment: @user2475632 Pls provide a fiddle or a link to what you are working on.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to place the container within another tag. The tag should be the one taking up the entire width of the page with css background attribute. In this case, I have chosen the html5 "section" tag. Below is an example. You can take a look at this **[jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ctnels/p1tz7Lq0/show/)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bootstrap 3 - Full width coloured blocks</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style type='text/css'>
    .colored-block {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 30px 0px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .purple { background: purple; }
    .green { background: green; }
    .blue { background: blue; }
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <section class="colored-block purple">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Header 1</h1>
            <p>Paragraph content goes here</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="colored-block green">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Header 2</h1>
            <p>Paragraph content goes here</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="colored-block blue">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Header 3</h1>
            <p>Paragraph content goes here</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is a [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ctnels/p1tz7Lq0/show/)**

Answer (score 0):

This should help you to understand your problem. 3 section made like red, green ,blue.

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <p class=text-danger> red color</p> 
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <p class=text-success> green color</p>      
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <p class=text-primary> blue color</p>       
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle, 3 columns, full height with background colors.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/scsGj/311/)

CSS:

```
html,body,.container-fluid
{
  height:100%;
}
.container
{
display:table;
width: 100%;
}
.row
{
height: 100%;
display: table-row;
}
.col-md-4, .col-xs-4
 {
display: table-cell;
float: none; 
}

.red{background:red;}

.green{background:green;}

.blue{background:blue;}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="red col-xs-4 col-md-4">.col-xs-4 .col-md-4</div>
 <div class="blue col-xs-4 col-md-4">.col-xs-4 .col-md-4</div>
 <div class="green col-xs-4 col-md-4">.col-xs-4 .col-md-4</div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve full-width coloured sections in Bootstrap by using 'container-fluid' instead of 'container'.
Example:
CSS:

```
.red{background:red;}
.green{background:green;}
.blue{background:blue;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="red col-xs-12">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-12 .col-md-12 .col-lg-12</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="blue col-xs-12">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-12 .col-md-12 .col-lg-12</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="green col-xs-12">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-12 .col-md-12 .col-lg-12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```